# Javascript replace function using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use javascript's replace function to replace a string. But it just replaces the first instance. So when I use regular global expressions,

```
var result = 'moaning|yes you|hello test|mission control|com on'.replace(/|/g, ';');
```

I get: http://jsfiddle.net/m8UuD/196/

I want to get:

> moaning;yes you;hello test;mission control;com on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply escape the pipe :

```
 'moaning|yes you|hello test|mission control|com on'.replace(/\|/g, ';');
```

[Here you'll find the list of regex special characters that you should generally escape](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html).

Comment: @SamiyaAkhtar Just make sure you Accept the answer when you are able to

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = 'moaning|yes you|hello test|mission control|com on'.replace(/\|/g, ';');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `.split()` and `.join()`:

```
'moaning|yes you|hello test|mission control|com on'.split('|').join(';')
```

Comment: This is probably a dumb question in this context, but do you know of any "performance issues" between this and `replace` with a Regex? I know both this and replace will effectively do the same thing, I'm just wondering. Is it "intensive" to split and then join? Especially compared to using a Regex? I'm sure in either case, it's not that important as this is a small string and only executed once, but I just thought I'd ask

Comment: @Ian: split/join seems to be a bit faster, at least on Chrome: http://jsperf.com/split-join-vs-regex2, but not by much

Comment: Thanks for providing that. I should've just done that myself. Of course on Firefox, I get the opposite results :) I guess I was wondering if you knew of something like "Well, regex gets compiled beforehand, therefore it can execute quicker" or something like that. And I also wonder if there's a relation to the size of the string. For some reason, I feel like split/join isn't as good as the size of the string increases.

Comment: @Ian: Sorry, I don't really know about that. I think there will be a point where creating the array and joining it will take up more time than the regex, but it might take a really long string: http://jsperf.com/split-join-vs-regex2/2

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the '|' like:

```
var result = 'moaning|yes you|hello test|mission control|com on'.replace(/\|/g, ';');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PM4PT/

Answer (score 1):

Many characters are reserved because have a special meaning in a regular expression, so to use one of them you need to "escape" it by placing a backslash `\` right before the special character. These are:

```
(   start of a sub-expression
)   end of a sub-expression
{   start of repetition range
}   end of a repetition range
[   start of a character set
]   end of a character set
+   one or more repetitions
*   zero or more repetitions
^   start of string
$   end of string
|   "or" connection between alternatives
\   start of special code or escape
/   start or end of regexp pattern
```

For example a regular exprerssion to match all open square bracket is `/\[/` (note the backslash). If you need to look for a backslash you must but a backslash in front of it (so doubling it).

Unfortunately there is no predefined Javascript function for "escaping" all special characters.